# minimize trigonometric function without calculus

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

I want to minimize the function $a\sin (x) + b\csc(x)$ without using calculus.

I know how to minimize a function like $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$. I write

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(x)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(x)\right) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x+\alpha)$$
where $\alpha=\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$. So I have the minimum when $\sin(x+\alpha)=-1$.

However, I don't know how to apply a similar procedure for $a\sin (x) + b\csc(x)$. Do I have to do something similar? Or maybe I can use the AM-GM inequality? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $\csc(x)=1/\sin(x)$, I think you can feel free to set $t=\sin(x)$ and minimize $at+b/t$ on $[-1,1]$. Of course, if $a$ and $b$ are positive, AM-GM would work, but you have to check if the minimizer is really between $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thanks! That's great! I now understand, but what about if $a=1$ and $b=9$? I get $\sin^2(x)=9$, which is not possible. However, the function has a minimum...

Comment: You just need to examine of the behavior of the function $at+b/t$ for $a=1$ and $b=9$ where $t$ ranges from $[-1,1]$. However, it seems that the function has no minimum in this case: If $\sin(x)\to 0^-$, then this function tends to $-\infty$. In addition, try drawing a graph for that: https://www.desmos.com/calculator